# ASP 301 redirect ignoring URL after domain name

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am attempting to redirect specific pages to their counterparts on a new replacement website, but the redirect is keeping the page name from the old website, resulting in a 404.

For example, the redirect I am currently getting is:
www.hadrianbooks.co.uk/about.asp -> www.barpublishing.com/about.asp

But what I want is:
www.hadrianbooks.co.uk/about.asp -> www.barpublishing.com/about-hadrian-books.html

Here is my code for this particular page:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.barpublishing.com/about-hadrian-books.html"
%>
```

The strange thing is that it was working perfectly a couple of days ago on all pages, and now doesn't work for any.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IIS Url Rewrite module to handle this, take a look at the following link:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module